# 19.10: Wired Headphones Issues

Tags: drivers, sound

I have both Ubuntu 19.10 and Windows installed on the same system on dual booting separate HDDs.

Wired sound (i.e. using wired headphones) works perfectly well on Windows but does not on Ubuntu (connecting Bluetooth speakers works). It does not seem like Linux is detecting the correct output device as when I run:

```
pactl list short sources
```

I get:

```
1. alsa_output.pci-0000_21_00.1.hdmi-stereo-extra1.monitor  module-alsa-card.c  s16le 2ch 44100Hz   RUNNING
2. alsa_output.usb-Generic_USB_Audio-00.analog-stereo.monitor   module-alsa-card.c  s16le 2ch 48000Hz   SUSPENDED
3. alsa_input.usb-Generic_USB_Audio-00.analog-stereo    module-alsa-card.c  s16le 2ch 48000Hz   RUNNING
```

How do I fix this?

My motherboard is an [Asrock TRX40 Creator](https://www.asrock.com/mb/AMD/TRX40%20Creator/#Specification).

Comment: There are at least three different Asrock Creator motherboards as per  https://www.google.com/search?q=site%3Aasrock.com+Asrock+Creator . Which do you have?

Comment: @K7AAY TRX40  Creator, updated